# Using network_mode='host' in docker-compose break run: host type networking can't be used with links

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

I dockerized a django app, and it need to connect to the HOST PostgresDB database. For that I do in the docker-compose:

```
  version: '2'
  services:
    web:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: DockerfileWeb
      command: gunicorn --timeout=300 --graceful-timeout=30 -w 2 --threads 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 cobros.wsgi
      volumes:
        - .:/code
        - /tmp:/tmp
      network_mode: "host"
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      restart: always
      environment:
        - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@127.0.0.1/postgres
        - PRODUCTION="true"
```

This work fine, EXCEPT if I try to run a command inside the docker, like:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py periodico
```

Now I get this error:

> [192.168.1.70] out: ERROR: Cannot create container for service web:
>   b"Conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links.
>   This would result in undefined behavior"

Answer (score 2):

This is because `docker-compose run` runs another container, a new container, that it is trying to attach to the same network as your `docker-compose up` container, so that they can work together.

This won't work with `host` networking, due to the publishing rules.

Instead, you could use `docker-compose exec web python manage.py periodico`

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late for the question, but docker still has the same problem. The problem with @RawKode for me was undefined variables such as DATABASE_URL. You can solve it with

`docker run -it --rm --net=host  <image_name> <command>`
adding `-e / --env-file` and variables names.

The command is longer but it works exactly the same as docker-compose run.